# C# I want change input to new language in output

Tags: c#, winforms

Ex.
input "Nattapong" 
change to thai language.
output "ณัฐพงษ์" (nat-ta-pong)

I try write it. (if over 100+)

I am sorry am not good english but i will try.
thank you.

Comment: Please post what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Microsoft Translator API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/getstarted.aspx)

> The Microsoft Translator API is a set of open web APIs that can be
>   integrated into any website or application, on any device (server, PC,
>   mobile, tablet, etc...) and operating system.

You can find some examples of the Microsoft Translator API [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator).